# A problem with Java is preventing me from loading an R package from GitHub

Tags: java, r

I had to update R and had to install Rtools40, and now that I've got version 4.0.0, I can't install a package from a GitHub repo. I *think* the problem relates to Java, so I removed old versions of Java, installed the new 64-bit version to match the 64-bit version of R I installed, and then I added Java to my Path. I'm on a Windows 10 system, so I did that by going to the Control Panel -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables... -> Path and then set the path to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin" because that's where "java.exe" is located. I *think* that's what I'm supposed to do.

Back in R, I'm able to use the package `xlsx` to save an Excel file, and I know that `xlsx` uses Java behind the scenes, so I would have thought that things were fine except that I cannot load an R package from my GitHub repo. When I try `devtools::install_github(repo = "shirewoman2/LaurasHelpers")`, here's the error I get:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'LaurasHelpers':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Laura Shireman/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have zero clue how to interpret that message. Other posts suggest that the problem is a mismatch between 32-bit and 64-bit systems, but I'm on 64-bit R and when I type `java -version` into the system command prompt, it looks like a 64-bit version there, too. The message it gives me is:

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm decent at coding in R but really, really not at doing things like reading/writing to the registry or doing complicated tasks in bash.

Here's my R session info:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
```

Comment: I got round a similar issue of installing a custom rjava package on windows by installing R but not installing the 32bit R when it gives you the option.

Comment: I didn't think I *had* installed the 32-bit version of R. In the session info, it says it's 64-bit.

Comment: 'C:/Users/Laura Shireman/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll' This file exists? 
Adding Java to the var env 'PATH' will help to find java in the terminal. But some software use also JAVA_HOME to locate it. This variable exists in your environment?

Comment: yes, but when you install it you get an option about the versions you want. 32 and 64 are automatically selected -- you have to manually deselect the 32 bit. But to be clear for me; rjava worked as expected for me but i couldn't install another package with rjava dependency from source - weird 32 bit errors.

Comment: @Erwan Daniel: No, I don't have a folder for rJava within my library. Should I? How would I get one?

Comment: '/win-library/4.0/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll' @user20650 Looks like you are right. It tries to load a 32bit library

Comment: @shirewoman2 Mmh I guess yes. I'm not familiar with R, did you try this in rstudio : **install.packages("rJava")** ?

Comment: @user20650: Yes! That worked! I uninstalled R, reinstalled and unclicked the 32-bit option, and now it works! THANK YOU! If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what solved it for me: Uninstall R again, and then re-install but be sure to uncheck the 32-bit option.

When I updated R, I had accepted all the defaults for installing it, but, as  @Erwan Daniel suggested, the problem was that the default for installing is to install both 32-bit and 64-bit. This was particularly confusing because my R session info said it was the 64-bit version.

Thanks!